# How to use environment modules in a ssh command line?

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, environment-variables, environment-modules

The **Environment Modules** package is used for dynamic modification of a user's environment (*debian package* `environment-modules`).

I would like to use `module` directly from a `ssh` command line. The purpose is to be able to execute commands on different nodes from a bash script executed on a front node. I don't want to explicitly update `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variables for each different node configuration.

When I directly connect to the node and then call `module` from the node, it is obviously working:

```
jyvet> ssh mynode
jyvet@mynode> module load gcc-6.0
jyvet@mynode> gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 6.0.1
```

But the following approach fails:

```
jyvet> ssh mynode "module load gcc-6.0; gcc --version"
command not found: module
gcc-4.8 (Debian 4.8.4-1) 4.8.4
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`module` is initialized by `/etc/profile.d/modules.sh` which is called by `/etc/profile` (which sets the environment variables at startup of the shell).

The `ssh` command execution shell is a **non-interactive shell** and does neither call `/etc/profile`, nor read config files.

**Here is the solution:**

```
jyvet> ssh mynode "source /etc/profile; module load gcc-6.0; gcc --version"
gcc (GCC) 6.0.1
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also invoke an login instance of `bash` so that the `/etc/profile.d/modules.sh` is `source`-ed automatically while login:

```
ssh mynode "bash -lc 'module load gcc-6.0; gcc --version'"
```