# Load environmental modules with SSH into server

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, server, environment-modules

I want to load a module on a server using SSH

```
ssh server.university.com "module load moduleX"
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
/usr/local/Modules/default/bin/modulecmd: error while loading shared` libraries: libtclx8.4.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried the solutions of this thread:

[How to use environment modules in a ssh command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36728685/how-to-use-environment-modules-in-a-ssh-command-line?newreg=15b0821e37dd44bda5723390e9c102e0)

That is,

```
 ssh server.university.com "bash -lc 'module load moduleX'" 

 bash: module: command not found
```

and

```
ssh server.university.com "source /etc/profile; module load moduleX"

/usr/local/Modules/default/bin/modulecmd: error while loading shared libraries: libtclx8.4.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I can load the module when I've already signed into the server. The reason for why I want to load it in the same command is that I in a pipeline want to do some estimations on the server, the rest on my computer.

Can someone please find a solution?

Here is the way I solved it:

It seems like the case I had a .bash_profile file prohibited the .profile file to be read. Took the .bash_profile file away and now it is working. I also added the following lines to the start of the .bashrc file which also was a part of the solution:

```
MODULE_VERSION=default
export MODULE_VERSION
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/pkg/tcltk/8.6.0/lib/:/usr/local/pkg/tcltk/8.6.0/lib/tclx8.4/
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: Couldn't you enter normally and then load it?

Comment: Do you know what specific environment variable is missing, and what value it should be set to?

Comment: Thanks for your replies @Jonatan and @Kenster! Jonatan, yes I can enter it normally and load it. I've added the reason for why I want to load it from the ssh to the question. Kenster, no I don't know. Do you know how to get this information?

Comment: I don't know anything more, but check the ssh man page, and try fiddling around until it works :) for example, I don't know what the c stands for in the flag -lc may be something should be changed.

Comment: Thank you! Now I've fiddled around a little bit ;-) See question for answer.

Comment: Looked all over for the answer to this. Found it here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36728686/1707865